# Need help for ResultSet in java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am using a `ResultSet` to retrieve  data from my SQL server. The code looks as follows:

```
ResultSet rs = getValueFormTable();
```

I'm looping over the `ResultSet` like this:

```
do{
   // process data
} while(rs.next());
```

Suppose there are 10 records and I am at the fourth value of the `ResultSet`. There comes the situation that I need take one value of the fifth `ResultSet` record again return back to the fourth `Resultset` record.

Is that possible?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not. You will have to process the data in two passes: Write everything to a list in the first, process the entries in the second.

Comment: You can convert ResultSet into array and use freely

Comment: @Simon, @marioosh, why not `resultSet.previous`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Suppose there are 10 records and i am in fourth ResultSet Value. There comes the situation that i need to need take one value of the fifth ResultSet again return back to the fourth Resultset. Is that possible in java?

You need "scrollable" `ResulSet` instances to achieve to scroll through the resultset; if you need to update the previous resultsets then you need scrollable and updatable resultsets (the last paragraph discusses updatable resultsets). Typically, `ResultSet`s are [`TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) and can be scrolled only in the forward direction using the `next()` method.

You will need to create a `ResultSet` instance of type [`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE) or [`TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE) to invoke other methods like `absolute()` and `previous()` for moving back and forth the `ResultSet`.

Creating a scrollable `ResultSet` requires you to specify the type of `ResultSet` returned by the `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` object, as the default type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` as stated earlier. A snippet demonstrating how to do so is shown below:

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = Connection.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
...
// You can now invoke rs.previous(), rs.absolute(n) etc. to move back and forth.
```

You would want to read up on how to specific the type of the ResultSet in the [`Connection.createStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28int,%20int%29), [`Connection.prepareStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) and [`Connection.prepareCall`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) methods.

If you want to modify the contents of the `ResultSet` and not just read from it, then you will need to create "updatable" ResultSets. This is easily done, by specifying the ResultSet concurrency type as [`CONCUR_UPDATABLE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#CONCUR_UPDATABLE). You can then invoke any of the `updateXXX` methods and follow them with an [`updateRow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateRow%28%29) method to update the underlying datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, if you have a [TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE) or [TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE) `ResultSet`

Use [`ResultSet.previous`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#previous%28%29)

(When you are in the first row, a call to `ResultSet.previous` will return `false` (but will not throw any exceptions), but any subsequent call to any methods that need the current row, like `resultSet.getString` will throw an `SQLException`. You can handle this by checking [`ResultSet.isFirst`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isFirst%28%29)

ResultSet has plenty of such methods, have a look at the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) once.

Comment: Be warned though, you can't count on it being implemented. For example the JDBC-ODBC driver which allows you to connect to MS Access just throws a NotImplementedException, which is rather embarassing.

Answer (score 1):

First `do-while` is not a good aproach to get the result out of the `ResultSet`. I would recoment you to use `while` Loop.

```
while( rs.next() ){
    ...
}
```

Second. yes there is a way to go back to the previous row if it is available.

```
if( rs.previous() ){
    //Do what value you want from previous record and jump to next record.
}
```

Comment: +1 for the loop, -0.2 for not mentioning that the ResultSet must be created as `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` or `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`.